# libmagickcore-dev not getting installed on Ubuntu 14.04. Geting the error " Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

Unable to install libmagickcore-dev on Ubuntu 14.04. Following is the log which sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev gives -

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmagickcore-dev : Depends: liblcms2-dev but it is not going to be    installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get update` then retry to install